# will my duraflex seams melt over a fire

Tags: experimental-physics, material-science

Good day ladies and gentlemen,
i do realize it may seem like a welding question but i assure you it is physics related.
i have built a non pressurized boiler that contains water to be used over an open fire in the bush for various purposes, i am using low heat aluminum welding rods called duraflex which have a melting point over 300celcius and am wondering with the water inside it will it prevent the duraflex seams at the base and sides from reaching that melting point and splitting. i am presuming its the same principal of a plastic bottle boiling water on a fire but am eager to see if anyone has tried or thinks it is in no way the same.
thank you very much for your pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under standard conditions water boils at 100 degC, and in theory a metal container will not rise above this temperature while there is water in it. However, the world is not ideal. There is always a temperature gradient across the metal. If the metal is a good heat conductor (as is Aluminium) and it is thin enough (a few mm), the temperature gradient will not be that great. However, beware the situation where the water only just covers the bottom of the container and the flames heat the sides. You can get a very hot rim and a cool (100 degC) bottom.

Comment: I should add one more caveat. If the water is boiling violently the temperature of the metal can increase beyond boiling point as it fails to remove heat fast enough.